# Scala lifting enums to native types with path-dependent types

Tags: scala, types, dependent-type, path-dependent-type

A couple of times now I've encountered an issue that I think should be resolvable by path dependent types, but I'm not sure that I've been able to do so in the most complete or correct way. It's not uncommon in the Java world to have an enumeration (or more often even a pseudo-enumeration in the form of a bunch of static values) that define a closed set that map to native types. `java.sql.Types` is a good example:

```java
public class Types {

    /**
     * <P>The constant in the Java programming language, sometimes referred
     * to as a type code, that identifies the generic SQL type
     * <code>BIT</code>.
     */
    public final static int BIT             =  -7;

    /**
     * <P>The constant in the Java programming language, sometimes referred
     * to as a type code, that identifies the generic SQL type
     * <code>TINYINT</code>.
     */
    public final static int TINYINT         =  -6;

    /**
     * <P>The constant in the Java programming language, sometimes referred
     * to as a type code, that identifies the generic SQL type
     * <code>SMALLINT</code>.
     */
    public final static int SMALLINT        =   5;
    // ...
}
```

I'd like to provide some mapping that will take me from these enums to their native types. So far I have something like this:

```
import java.sql.{Types, ResultSet}

trait SqlType {
  def typeValue:Int
  type Value
  def getValue(rs:ResultSet, idx:Int):Value
}

object SqlType {

  object SqlInt extends SqlType {
    type Value = Int
    def typeValue = Types.INTEGER
    def getValue(rs:ResultSet, idx:Int) = rs.getInt(idx)
  }

  object SqlString extends SqlType {
    type Value = String
    def typeValue = Types.NVARCHAR
    def getValue(rs:ResultSet, idx:Int) = rs.getString(idx)
  }


  def getSqlType(typeValue:Int):SqlType = typeValue match {
    case Types.INTEGER => SqlInt
    case Types.NVARCHAR => SqlString
  }

  implicit class ResultSetExtras(rs:ResultSet) {
    def getCell(idx:Int, sqlType:SqlType):sqlType.Value = sqlType.getValue(rs, idx)
  }
}
```

This is a bit wonky however, as I need to get the concrete `SqlType` instance before hand and pass it in as an argument of the function to get the proper path-dependent type. So it doesn't seem like I can do something like this, which is what I'd really like:

```
  implicit class ResultSetExtras2(rs:ResultSet) {
    def getCell2(idx:Int):SqlType#Value = getSqlType(rs.getMetaData.getColumnType(idx)).getValue(rs, idx) 
  }
```

(note the return type of `SqlType#Value` rather than the path-dependent `sqlType.Value`. Is there a (better) way to achieve this in pure scala? I suspect that something like shapeless or macros might help, but if possible I'd like to know if it's possible with path dependent types (or macros indeed in preference to shapeless).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that it is impossible **at compilation time** for `rs.getCell(2)` to know what the exact concrete type of value will be produced. Path-dependent types won't help here. The type of the result can only be known **at runtime**. It's not a problem if you select the abstract type of `SqlType` as the return value (as would be the case with java). You just can't get the *actual* type represented by `SqlType#Value`.